# sudo cannot open /etc/sudoers

Tags: arch-linux, sudo

`sudo` does not work.
I have Arch Linux installed on a USB key formatted with BTRFS.
Here's the output when I run 'sudo':

```
$ sudo
sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

$ ls -l /etc/sudoers
-r--r----- 1 root root 2849 May 18 15:00 /etc/sudoers

$ lsattr /etc/sudoers
--------------- /etc/sudoers

$ ls -ld /etc
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 2476 May 25 13:45 /etc

$ ls -ld /
drwx------ 1 root root 142 May 25 06:51 /

$ ls -l $(which sudo)
---s--x--x 2 root root 123995 May 25 13:10 /usr/bin/sudo

$ strace -u ross sudo true 2>&1 | egrep '(sudo|set.*[ug].*id)'
execve("/usr/bin/sudo", ["sudo", "true"], [/* 30 vars */]) = 0
read(3, "31799 (sudo) R 31796 31796 31754"..., 1024) = 223
lstat64("/etc/sudo.conf", 0xbfcddeb0)   = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
stat64("/usr/lib/sudoers.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=235092, ...}) = 0
open("/usr/lib/sudoers.so", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
stat64("/usr/lib/sudoers.so", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0755, st_size=235092, ...}) = 0
setresuid32(0, -1, -1)                  = 0
setresgid32(-1, 0, -1)                  = 0
setresuid32(-1, 1, -1)                  = 0
lstat64("/etc/sudoers", 0xbfcddd60)     = -1 EACCES (Permission denied)
setresuid32(-1, 0, -1)                  = 0
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4
write(2, "unable to stat /etc/sudoers", 27unable to stat /etc/sudoers) = 27
setresuid32(-1, 1, -1)                  = 0
setresgid32(-1, -1, -1)                 = 0
setresuid32(-1, 0, -1)                  = 0
setresuid32(-1, 0, -1)                  = 0
setresgid32(-1, 1000, -1)               = 0
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4
write(2, "no valid sudoers sources found, "..., 40no valid sudoers sources found, quitting) = 40
write(2, "sudo", 4sudo)                     = 4


$ ltrace -u ross sudo true 2>&1 | egrep '(sudo|stat|set.*[ug].*id)'
bindtextdomain("sudo", "/usr/share/locale")      = "/usr/share/locale"
textdomain("sudo")                               = "sudo"
fopen("/proc/31813/stat", "r")                   = 0x9e51d40
__xstat(3, "/dev/console", 0xbffd6074)           = 0
__xstat(3, "/dev/wscons", 0xbffd6074)            = -1
__xstat(3, "/dev/pts/4", 0xbffd6074)             = 0
__lxstat64(3, "/etc/sudo.conf", 0xbffd9040)      = -1
strlen("sudo")                                   = 4
memcpy(0x09e51e71, "sudo", 4)                    = 0x09e51e71
__xstat64(3, "/usr/lib/sudoers.so", 0xbffd810c)  = 0
dlopen("/usr/lib/sudoers.so", 257 <unfinished ...>
dlsym(0x09e51ef8, "sudoers_policy")              = 0xb75af520
__xstat64(3, "/usr/lib/sudoers.so", 0xbffd810c)  = 0
dlopen("/usr/lib/sudoers.so", 257)               = 0x09e51ef8
dlsym(0x09e51ef8, "sudoers_io")                  = 0xb75af560
fputs("sudo", 0xb7760920sudo)                        = 1
fputs("unable to stat /etc/sudoers", 0xb7760920unable to stat /etc/sudoers) = 1
fputs("sudo", 0xb7760920sudo)                        = 1
fputs("no valid sudoers sources found, "..., 0xb7760920no valid sudoers sources found, quitting) = 1
fputs("sudo", 0xb7760920sudo)                        = 1
+++ exited (status 1) +++
```

Comment: What about `ls -ld /etc`?

Comment: Added in latest edit.

Comment: Show output of `ls -l $(which sudo)` , that's the source of problem

Comment: Have you verified sudoers syntax has no problems?

Comment: Added both in edits, no syntax errors...

Comment: The system indicates a question has been solved as long as an answer is accepted; you don't need to edit it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok , you don't seem to have access for / (can't cd),

Can you try `chmod 755 /`

Comment: @UlrichDangel really ? I tried a simple program , with those calls , even if the program is suid-ed , the function will still return -1. ( I did `chown root ./suid_test` and `chmod 4755 ./suid_test`) , source code:  http://pastebin.mozilla.org/1650215

Comment: './suid_test':
    0
    setresuid: 0
    0

Comment: Doesn't fix the issue

Comment: "strace -uuli -f ./suid_test |& grep uid" produces nothing.

Comment: "strace -f ./suid_test |& grep uid" produces: execve("./suid_test", ["./suid_test"], [/* 22 vars */]) = 0
geteuid32()                             = 0
setresuid32(0, -1, -1)                  = 0
geteuid32()                             = 0
write(1, "0\nsetresuid: 0\n0\n", 170
setresuid: 0

Comment: @RossMcDonald Ulrich was right .. now i think i know the problem  ,see my update

Comment: @warl0ck thank you, that worked. I was originally using it as a chroot to build packages, so I changed the ownership so that I could cd into it. Thanks

Comment: This answer is godsend. It resolved including but not limited to `su`, `sudo`, `pam authentication` errors, services not starting / keyboard stopping to respond / boot freezes and what not after I migrated my Ubuntu filesystem from `ext4` to `btrfs` (thrice!). Oh, what didn't I try! So much time spent in frustration and all I needed was a `chmod` on that btrfs subvolume! I now officially owe you a round of drinks, if we ever meet in this lifetime.

Answer (score 1):

The executable needs to be setuid and owned by root:

```
$ ls -la /usr/bin/sudo
---s--x--x 2 root root 173154 Oct 19  2010 /usr/bin/sudo
```

Your binary is missing one of those traits. Do this (as root):

```
# chown root /usr/bin/sudo
# chmod u+xs /usr/bin/sudo
```

Comment: I may be wrong but i don't think the suid bit is missing as the return value for `setresuid32(0, -1, -1)` and `setresgid32(-1, 0, -1)` is both time 0 which indicates that the program has the correct permissions

Comment: Ulrich Dangel is right, sadly. That makes no difference (and I had already tried that).

Answer (score 0):

how did you install it?
you have to mount the partition on the usb-stick as root for the installation.
I don't know why but it worked for me only this way.
Afterwards you can mount the partition as user and update it via rsync and no problem should appear (but I haven't tested this extensively).

There is most probably something broken in the user mount system.

Answer (score -2):

Follow these steps:

```
~# chmod 440 /etc/sudoers
~# chmod -R 755 /root
~# chmod -R 755 /etc
~# chmod 755 /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php
```

Comment: -1: This is very bad advice. You should not blindly smash the permissions on everything in `/root` and `/etc`. There's a reason these files get installed with varying permissions. The advice to blindly set executable permissions on all of these files is bogus; few files in these trees require it. And the advice to give world-read & -execute permissions to everything in `/root` and `/etc` is stunningly bad; you might as well email the root password to every user who can log into that system while you're at it, because you've already given them full run of the box by doing that.